# LightGBM accuracy not increasing with iterations on Validation Set?

Tags: boosting, overfitting, lightgbm

I am training a model with LightGBM, and I am getting an output like this:

```
[LightGBM] [Info] Total Bins 1981
[LightGBM] [Info] Number of data points in the train set: 28632, number of used features: 15
[LightGBM] [Info] Start training from score 2.534713
[20]    training's rmse: 4.7065 valid_1's rmse: 4.79156
[40]    training's rmse: 4.45158        valid_1's rmse: 4.61878
[60]    training's rmse: 4.32291        valid_1's rmse: 4.55663
[80]    training's rmse: 4.24446        valid_1's rmse: 4.53266
[100]   training's rmse: 4.18674        valid_1's rmse: 4.52748
[120]   training's rmse: 4.13661        valid_1's rmse: 4.52959
[140]   training's rmse: 4.09082        valid_1's rmse: 4.53327
[160]   training's rmse: 4.04819        valid_1's rmse: 4.53705
[180]   training's rmse: 4.00448        valid_1's rmse: 4.53943
[200]   training's rmse: 3.96052        valid_1's rmse: 4.54488
[220]   training's rmse: 3.9187 valid_1's rmse: 4.5526
[240]   training's rmse: 3.87888        valid_1's rmse: 4.55612
[260]   training's rmse: 3.83932        valid_1's rmse: 4.56151
[280]   training's rmse: 3.8001 valid_1's rmse: 4.56596
[300]   training's rmse: 3.76323        valid_1's rmse: 4.56899
[320]   training's rmse: 3.72648        valid_1's rmse: 4.57288
[340]   training's rmse: 3.68954        valid_1's rmse: 4.57776
[360]   training's rmse: 3.65472        valid_1's rmse: 4.58399
[380]   training's rmse: 3.62083        valid_1's rmse: 4.58822
[400]   training's rmse: 3.58848        valid_1's rmse: 4.59112
[420]   training's rmse: 3.55622        valid_1's rmse: 4.5942
[440]   training's rmse: 3.52427        valid_1's rmse: 4.59629
[460]   training's rmse: 3.49288        valid_1's rmse: 4.5998
[480]   training's rmse: 3.46305        valid_1's rmse: 4.60098
[500]   training's rmse: 3.4332 valid_1's rmse: 4.604
[520]   training's rmse: 3.40395        valid_1's rmse: 4.60809
[540]   training's rmse: 3.37517        valid_1's rmse: 4.61122
[560]   training's rmse: 3.34607        valid_1's rmse: 4.61451
[580]   training's rmse: 3.31775        valid_1's rmse: 4.61881
[600]   training's rmse: 3.28888        valid_1's rmse: 4.62112
[620]   training's rmse: 3.26158        valid_1's rmse: 4.62205
[640]   training's rmse: 3.23438        valid_1's rmse: 4.62703
[660]   training's rmse: 3.2086 valid_1's rmse: 4.63075
[680]   training's rmse: 3.18285        valid_1's rmse: 4.63385
[700]   training's rmse: 3.15612        valid_1's rmse: 4.63661
[720]   training's rmse: 3.12905        valid_1's rmse: 4.64054
[740]   training's rmse: 3.10485        valid_1's rmse: 4.64305
[760]   training's rmse: 3.07981        valid_1's rmse: 4.6468
[780]   training's rmse: 3.05544        valid_1's rmse: 4.65087
[800]   training's rmse: 3.03116        valid_1's rmse: 4.65354
[820]   training's rmse: 3.00748        valid_1's rmse: 4.65625
[840]   training's rmse: 2.98355        valid_1's rmse: 4.65951
[860]   training's rmse: 2.96051        valid_1's rmse: 4.66279
[880]   training's rmse: 2.93658        valid_1's rmse: 4.66475
[900]   training's rmse: 2.91332        valid_1's rmse: 4.66645
[920]   training's rmse: 2.89188        valid_1's rmse: 4.67055
[940]   training's rmse: 2.87073        valid_1's rmse: 4.67544
[960]   training's rmse: 2.84836        valid_1's rmse: 4.67783
[980]   training's rmse: 2.82654        valid_1's rmse: 4.68047
[1000]  training's rmse: 2.80509        valid_1's rmse: 4.68257
[1020]  training's rmse: 2.78431        valid_1's rmse: 4.68481
[1040]  training's rmse: 2.76303        valid_1's rmse: 4.68846
[1060]  training's rmse: 2.74237        valid_1's rmse: 4.69077
[1080]  training's rmse: 2.7221 valid_1's rmse: 4.69346
[1100]  training's rmse: 2.70158        valid_1's rmse: 4.69541
[1120]  training's rmse: 2.68161        valid_1's rmse: 4.69885
[1140]  training's rmse: 2.66289        valid_1's rmse: 4.70274
[1160]  training's rmse: 2.6443 valid_1's rmse: 4.70658
[1180]  training's rmse: 2.62565        valid_1's rmse: 4.70889
[1200]  training's rmse: 2.60685        valid_1's rmse: 4.71195
```

From [20] -> [1200[, the RMSE of the validation set has barely changed, whereas the test set's RMSE has improved quite a bit.

I know this is a clear sign of overfitting, but is the fact that the validation set isn't improving at all a sign of something?

Is the model learning relations that only exist in the training set somehow? I don't really understand how the model can be improving on the training set so much, whereas the validation set remains static?

Comment: Yes, that's overfitting

Comment: In the paragraph following the code output, you mention **test** scores, but you haven't included those or mentioned them elsewhere; was that a typo?